# Why can’t I divide by $n^2$ here to evaluate the limit?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, limits-without-lhopital

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}{ \frac {n^2}{1+2+…+n}}$$

Here, if we divide and multiply by $n^2$, the numerator becomes $1$ and the limit of the denominator becomes $0$ then, the entire limit becomes infinite. But if I actually do the summation of the numbers in the denominator and then divide by $n^2$ I get a finite answer $2$… I can’t understand why this happens?

Comment: "and the limit of the denominator becomes 0" -- This is where your error is.  Why do you think the limit of the denominator would become 0?

Comment: $1+...+n = {1 \over 2} n (n+1)$ so the denominator does not go to zero.

Comment: Your mistake is assuming that the denominator is zero when divided by $n^2$. Recall the formula $$1+2+\dots+n = \frac{1}{2}n(n+1)$$

Comment: @copper.hat:  I think you meant $\frac12$ where you typed $\frac1n$; never mind, it appears you corrected it

Comment: The sum in the denominator does indeed have its terms smaller and smaller as $n\to\infty$, but.. there are more and more terms, so these two factors "pull the opposite ways" and it is hard to see which one "wins". You need to do the summation and see that the denominator actually converges to $1/2$.

Comment: In fact, if you've ever studied integration, you may see that the sum in the denominator is the _upper Darboux sum_ for $\int_0^1 x\, dx$ for the partition $(0,1/n,2/n,\ldots,n/n)$ of $[0,1]$ and so it converges to $\int_0^1 x\, dx=1/2$. The point here is: all those Riemann/Darboux sums have the property that they are sums of smaller and smaller terms, while having more and more terms, and as the limit they have some integral.  (Which is a common method of calculating the limit.)

Comment: As an easier illustration, if your sum was $n$ copies of $1$ and you divided throughout by $n$ you would get a sum of terms $\frac 1n$ - the individual terms would go to zero, but sum would always by $\frac nn =1$

Comment: @MarkBennet Very nice illustrative example.

Comment: I am somewhat beginning to understand what you mean by why the denominator will not tend to 0 even as individual terms tend to 0 but our teacher taught us that Lim f(x) + g(x) = Lim f(x) + Lim g(x) and applying that on terms like 1/n^2 + 2/n^2 etc it becomes 0

Comment: @jsalgeorge "but our teacher taught us that Lim f(x) + g(x) = Lim f(x) + Lim g(x)" -- This is still a valid theorem, but it doesn't apply when the number of terms depends on the variable in the limit or when there are infinitely many terms.  In principle, doing so is interchanging limits, and this is arguably _the_ central problem in calculus: we can't always interchange limits.  Many important theorems simply dictate when we can, but in particular, we cannot here.

Answer (score 6):

You say that $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{1/n^2+2/n^2+\cdots+1/n}=\infty, $$ since the denominator goes to zero, which is not true because the number of terms involved in the sum of the denominator changes within the value of $n$, so its not correct. A direct approach using $1+2+\cdots+n=n(n+1)/2$ gives us that $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{n^2}{1+2+\cdots+n}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{2n^2}{n^2+n}=2.$$

Answer (score 1):

As notice in the comments and in the given fine answer the denominator divided by $n^2$ tends to $\frac12 $ and not to zero. The key fact is that in the limit we are summing "an infinite number of terms" (that is a larger and larger number of terms) and for that reason their sum can be finite, even if each term tends to zero.

As an alternative, we can also obtain the result by [Cesaro-Stolz theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem)

$$\frac {(n+1)^2-n^2}{(1+2+\ldots+n+n+1)-(1+2+\ldots+n)}=\frac{2n+1}{n+1} \to 2$$